# What the function apply() in scikit-learn can do?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

In scikit-learn new  version ,there is a new function called `apply()` in Gradient boosting. I'm really confused about it .

Does it like the method:`GBDT + LR` that facebook has used?
If dose, how can we make it work like `GBDT + LR`?

Comment: Use the source. It's open-source so you can have a look at what it does.

Answer (score 3):

From the Sci-Kit Documentation

> apply(X)  Apply trees in the ensemble to X, return leaf indices

This function will take input data X and each data point (x) in it will be applied to each non-linear classifier tree. After application, data point x will have associated with it the leaf it end up at for each decision tree. This leaf will have its associated classes ( 1 if binary ).

`apply(X)` returns the above information, which is of the form `[n_samples, n_estimators, n_classes]`.

Thus, the `apply(X)` function doesn't really have much to do with the Gradient Boosted Decision Tree + Logic Regression (GBDT+LR) classification and feature transform methods. It is a function for the application of data to an existing classification model.

I'm sorry if I have misunderstood you in any way, though a few grammar/syntax errors in your question made it harder to decipher.

Answer (score 1):

apply(X) returns raw indices of tree leaves, I think you need to transform the discrete indices into one-hot encoding style and then you can perform the lr step.
For example ,apply(X) would return

```
[
 [[1], [2], [3], [4]],
 [[2], [3], [4], [5]],
 [[3], [4], [5], [6]]
]
```

where n_samples = 3, n_estimators=4, and n_classes=1.
you must first know the number of each tree used in the gbm classifier. As we know, gbm use sklearn decision tree regressor, according to sklearn decision tree regressor apply function, we get:

> X_leaves : array_like, shape = [n_samples,]
>               For each datapoint x in X, return the index of the leaf x
>               ends up in. Leaves are numbered within
>               `[0; self.tree_.node_count)`, possibly with gaps in the
>               numbering.

AS a result, you need to pad zero into other indices. Take the above example, if the first tree has tree_.node_count = 5, then the first column of the three samples should be transferred into:

```
[
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
]
```

process other columns correspondingly then you can get what you want. Hope it will help you!